# SPARQL 1.1 Algebra converting multiset to sequence

Tags: sparql

In the [SPARQL 1.1 specification - 18.2.3 Examples of Mapped Graph Patterns](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#sparqlAlgebraExamples)- Example: Pattern involving a subquery:

```
{ ?s :p ?o . {SELECT DISTINCT ?o {?o ?p ?z} } }
Join(
   BGP(?s :p ?o) ,
   ToMultiSet(
     Distinct(Project(BGP(?o ?p ?z), {?o})) )
 )
```

There should not be a `ToList` call after BGP evaluation since `Project` takes a sequence of solution modifiers as input?, i.e.:

```
{ ?s :p ?o . {SELECT DISTINCT ?o {?o ?p ?z} } }
Join(
   BGP(?s :p ?o) ,
   ToMultiSet(
     Distinct(Project(ToList(BGP(?o ?p ?z)), {?o})) )
 )
```

Comment: Thank you for the report. I've added it to the SPARQl errata for the RDF working group (which is also updating SPARQL).

Comment: @AndyS Do you agree to the point?