# SPARQL 1.1 algebra: Nesting Aggregation in Selection

Tags: sparql

In SPARQL 1.1, aggregation using the [`AggregateJoin` algebra operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregateAlgebra) results in a **set** of solution mappings. Since aggregation is used in combination with projection, that leads to `AggregateJoin` being nested in `Project`. However, `Project` expects a **sequence** of solution mappings whereas `AggregateJoin` provides a set. There is a step `ToList` [18.2.5 Converting Solution Modifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#convertSolMod) that converts a multiset to a list upon processing solution modifiers (since SPARQL evaluation in general yields multisets). Should that not also account for `AggregateJoin` by some form of a function, e.g., `SetToList`, or `SetToMultiSet` that is called before `ToList`?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77978291/sparql-1-1-algebra-converting-multiset-to-sequence